# Audacious: How to play midi files?

Tags: 16.04, midi, playback, audacious

How do I play midi files under Audacious? I am currently running Xenial Xerus LTS with:

```
andrew@athens:~$ audacious --version
Audacious 3.6.2 (Ubuntu package)
```

I have been using this Wiki midi file to test:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/MIDI_sample.mid

Comment: **Note:** This Ask Ubuntu question and accepted answer do not deal with Audacious at all: http://askubuntu.com/q/771353/57576

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Audacious under Xenial Xerus comes equipped with the AMIDI-Plug (Midi Player) plugin but what is missing *by default* is:

1. An appropriate Sound Font
2. The appropriate setup from within Audacious to *use* this Sound Font

To get a decent Sound Font run the following command from a Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs
```

This places a sound font in `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2` and this can be sourced from within the Audacious preferences as this screenshot shows:

[image: screenshot]

And now [the test midi file from Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/55/MIDI_sample.mid) will play back in all the glory of that uniquely midi sound:

[image]

**References:**

- [Audacious: How-to: MIDI playback](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/boards/1/topics/1143)

Comment: Worked great for me.

Comment: @Santropedro Good to that this old answer is still useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (Lubuntu on my laptop)
I ran

```
sudo apt-get install fluid-soundfont-gm fluid-soundfont-gs
```

but then I had to manually insert the sound font file into Audacious using the following menus:

```
services > plugins > Input > AMIDI-plug(MIDI player)
```

then clicked `settings`, then `+` to add the sound font. Once the sound font file location was added to AMIDI-Plugin everything worked great.

Sound font file --->  `/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2`