# Update firefox to Firefox Quantum

Tags: firefox, update-manager

I have heard alot about [firefox Quantum](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/), I have downloaded it and it is running fine. But the problem is I want to update my existing firefox which came installed by default, so as to have all my history, password etc to be on the latest i.e. Quantum one. Currently, it does not have any browsing history or any other data I had on my old-school browser.

Comment: Just use "Software Updater" application. If it doesn't show yet, wait for a few hours. The update should be available soon.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6339/how-do-i-install-the-latest-stable-version-of-firefox) because the vast majority of Ubuntu users who want to upgrade from Firefox 56 to Firefox 57 will (and should) strongly prefer simply to update their installed packages, as described in the answer here. There is no need to do anything special to get this update. As long as this is considered a duplicate of that question, people will skip over the answer here and do things they don't need or want to do and that they'd never have done if they knew what it said.

Comment: agreed @EliahKagan. I will update the question, in that case. because the other answer does not specify to update.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I should explain better: **The vast majority of people who want Firefox Quantum have no idea that it would be provided as a security update** because they don't want it for that reason and (in the larger world outside Ubuntu) it is not being advertised primarily as one. To know that because it includes bug fixes and `firefox` is an exception to [the usual policy](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates), the *new features* will be in the Ubuntu version too, is to know the answer. Nobody who needs an answer to this will get it by visiting that one and reading that answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: As far as Firefox Quantum is concerned, it's now available for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu from the repositories. See [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) Thanks to [Videonauth](https://askubuntu.com/users/522934/videonauth) for pointing that out.

If you simply can't wait to try the latest version of Firefox, The Ubuntu Mozilla Security Team has a PPA at https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Although it's advisable to wait until they've finished vetting, if you want to do some testing on a non production system of the bleeding edge Firefox browser you can easily do so.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

restart firefox.

**Note:** Regardless of how you obtain Firefox Quantum, you'll lose your Ubuntu customization extension (and any other incompatible extensions/add-ons you may be using like the SE AutoReview comments add-on, and Flashblock to name 3). So far it's a very responsive browser. For those of you that are interested in the changes to the extensions there's an interesting article [here.](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-add-technology-modernizing?as=u&utm_source=inproduct)

**Edit:** For those of you (like me) who aren't comfortable with losing the SE AutoReview comments add-on and are unwilling to wait and see if a version compatible with Firefox Quantum comes along, a quick fix is [the extension for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/SE%20AutoComments) (if you have that or are willing to install it)

Comment: On most versions which are still supported firefox has already been updated to 57 in the repositories :)